# spring boot mongodb config write/read+slaveOk

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

`mongodb://mongo-write,mongo-read/db?slaveOk=true`  not work

how can use in spring boot yml config?

Comment: What `spring boot` version is used?

Comment: @nurgasemetey  1.3.5.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

use `?readPreference=secondary` replace `?slaveOk=true`